# Haskell: encoding a generic schema

Tags: haskell, schema

To begin with, some motivation: I want to take configuration from multiple places - command line arguments, possibly config files, some other service. I don't have any particular care for the *format* of these sources. What I would like to do is describe a schema for that configuration and have pluggable sources generate parsers/writers for that config as necessary. The schema should also encode things such as help text, possibly completion options, etc.

Here's the basis of what I have so far:

```
data Name =
    LongName String
  | ShortName Char

data OptionDefault a = OptionDefault (Maybe a) (Maybe (a -> String))

data OptionDescr = OptionDescr {
    odNames :: [Name]
  , odSummary :: String
  , odDetail :: String
}

data Option a = Option {
    oReader :: Monad m => String -> m a
  , oDefault :: OptionDefault a
  , oDescr :: OptionDescr
}
```

The thing I'm not sure how to do is *compose* these - e.g. to define a config section as being, say, three options of types `Option Foo`, `Option Bar` and `Option Baz` as well as a function `f :: Foo -> Bar -> Baz -> FBBSection`. This is a different question to composing the *Parsers*, which should be done at a later date by a generator for the specific format.

The only thing I can think of is to store the options as some kind of HList, and force some kind of fold composition for `f` - any other ideas?

Comment: It'd be worth looking at `optparse-applicative` and `cmdargs` as prior art.

Comment: `optparse-applicative` was where I started. I love the approach it takes, but because it composes the parsers, the approach doesn't work here - e.g. the heterogenous types of the options get lost.

Comment: Both of those libraries use Applicatives to solve exactly that problem though. The heterogenous types are eliminated by applying a function which consumes them. If that function is, for instance, a bunch of applications of `(,)` then you'll arrive at basically the exact structure of HList naturally.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Applicative instance for Option:

```
foo :: Option Foo
bar :: Option Bar
baz :: Option Baz
f :: Foo -> Bar -> Baz -> FBBSection

fbbSection :: Option FBBSection
fbbSection = f <$> foo <*> bar <*> baz
```

Now, the trouble is in writing the Applicative instance.  First of all, you need a Functor instance, but you can't really provide one: `OptionDefault` is an invariant functor because its type parameter `a` occurs in both a positive position `Maybe a` and in a negative position `Maybe (a -> String)`.  The Functor typeclass in Haskell is only for covariant functors.

You might re-examine your data to see if you can make it covariant.  There *might* be an equivalent for `Applicative` that is invariant though I'm not sure; I'm not sure how currying works for isomorphisms, if it does at all, and `Applicative` is actually rather dependent on currying, from a categorical perspective.

After you got though all of that, you'd need to define how your Applicative combined OptionDescr values.